# How to parse multiple Set-Cookie generated by cpprestsdk?

Tags: c++, regex, httpcookie, cpprest-sdk

```
tgw_l7_route=d0bf4a9ab78d53762b596c0a48dabcdf; Expires=Thu, 03-May-2018 11:42:51 GMT; Path=/, session=a1d25e28-0084-421d-ae71-9ae18c7f6b50; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 10:42:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
```

There are 2 Set-Cookie items joined by ', ', the problem with this string is that the expires date also contains ', '.

This string is generated by cpprestsdk library. I need to parse it and generate a 'Cookie' header in order to send to server in on-going requests.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  std::string cookieStr = "tgw_l7_route=d0bf4a9ab78d53762b596c0a48dabcdf; Expires=Thu, 03-May-2018 11:42:51 GMT; Path=/, session=a1d25e28-0084-421d-ae71-9ae18c7f6b50; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 10:42:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/";
  std::regex rgx(", [^ ]+=");
  std::sregex_token_iterator iter(cookieStr.begin(),
    cookieStr.end(),
    rgx,
    -1);
  std::sregex_token_iterator end;
  for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
}
```

Above code outputs:

```
tgw_l7_route=d0bf4a9ab78d53762b596c0a48dabcdf; Expires=Thu, 03-May-2018 11:42:51 GMT; Path=/ 
a1d25e28-0084-421d-ae71-9ae18c7f6b50; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 10:42:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
```

Is there a way to keep "session=" in the second string?

Comment: Or, is there a way to split string by beginning of pattern ", [^ ]+="?

Comment: You seem to need `"(?=, [^ ]+=)"` or `"(?=,\\s*\\S+=)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, great, thanks!    ", (?=[^ ]+=)" works. What's the terminology is this?

Comment: A positive lookahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the pattern you use into a [**positive lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), a *non-consuming* construct.

```
"(?=, [^ ]+=)"
 ^^^        ^
```

This construct matches a location in the string that is immediately followed with a `,`, a space, and then 1+ chars other than space and then a `=` sign *without* pushing the value matched into the match stack. It means that the matched text is not split upon, and it remains in the resulting array of split chunks.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6yio5M/1).

[C++ demo](https://ideone.com/HOWk3M):

```
std::string cookieStr = "tgw_l7_route=d0bf4a9ab78d53762b596c0a48dabcdf; Expires=Thu, 03-May-2018 11:42:51 GMT; Path=/, session=a1d25e28-0084-421d-ae71-9ae18c7f6b50; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 10:42:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/";
std::regex rgx("(?=, [^ ]+=)");
std::sregex_token_iterator iter(cookieStr.begin(),
  cookieStr.end(),
  rgx,
  -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
```

Output:

```
tgw_l7_route=d0bf4a9ab78d53762b596c0a48dabcdf; Expires=Thu, 03-May-2018 11:42:51 GMT; Path=/
, session=a1d25e28-0084-421d-ae71-9ae18c7f6b50; Expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 10:42:51 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
```